# How to Use Mysql PDO driver with hacklang/hhvm

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hhvm, hacklang

I am getting a pdo exception "could not find driver" when trying to access MySql through PDO using hacklang/hhvm (compiled today). I tried installing php5-mysql but I'm not even sure that is helpful because I'm not sure of the relationship between php and hacklang especially in terms of extensions. What can I do to get PDO working on hacklang?

Update:

I found this list of supported extensions:
https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extensions

PDO and MySql are both on there but should I be looking for mysql_pdo? Or is there some configuring I need to do?

Comment: Also I've been working on a guide for anyone here who is getting started. I wasted 2 hours compiling not realizing their was a package available: https://joltup.com/how-to-install-hacklang-on-ubuntu-apache-nginx/

Comment: I think the Hack language and the HHVM support for it are waaaay too young right now for a consistent knowledge base about them to exist. I suggest waiting a few weeks :)

Comment: Well that's exactly why I'm working through this. No way I'll put my company's code on it yet...But I want to eventually. I figure wading through the installation, bugs, and asking questions here will be one of the best ways to work out the knowledge base. It's a community effort, right?

Comment: Facebook employee here but not working on the HHVM team. The error you're getting seems to be runtime and not related to hacklang - maybe try asking in #hhvm (IRC)?

Comment: it works on my machine, I compiled HHVM on ubuntu 12.04 using following guide: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-12.04.

Comment: I am looking for this too. Keep getting PDO not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it merely by rebuilding from scratch per the advice on peoples on the IRC channel. I honestly don't know what went wrong.